# Can't delete folder - operation not permitted

Tags: macos, terminal

I try to delete the folders in my update directory `/Library/Updates`, because my updates are corrupt and are failing. I need them to get downloaded again.

I tried it with the terminal like this `sudo rm -Rf 041-57076` but it does fail with `operation not permitted`.

The output of **ls -lO /Library/Updates/** is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root wheel restricted 288 27 Mai 15:54 041-57076
...
```

I only posted the relevant line

Comment: Can you run `ls -lO /Library/Updates/` (letter O) and add the output to the question?

Comment: @nohillside, I added the relevant line from the output to the question

Comment: Similar questions have come up before, see link in yellow box on top. Not sure it will solve your update problem though. But if it doesn't, please ask a new question describing the problem in more detail.

Comment: @nohillside, I just tried it. I booted into recovery mode, opened the terminal and executed `csrutil disable; reboot` but I still get `operation not permitted`

Comment: I got the message `Successfully disabled System integrity protection`

Comment: @nohillside, I tried it again, this time it worked. Not sure why I had to do it twice. At second time I was only executing `csrutil disable` and after it `reboot`. Thanks for your answer!!