# Can't remove systems folder from a faulty installation of Mac Catalina

Tags: mac, catalina, permission, filesystem, sip

I had Mojave installed on my late 2012 Mac mini, and attempted to install Catalina on it using the internet recovery mode. This install was made to the `/Volumes/Local` disc, and it failed miserably not allowing me to reboot properly. I was then able to go back to a Mojave installation, and continued with a successful install from an USB drive to the `/Volumes/SSD`disc, and I'm now trying to cleanup the garbage from the other install.

I've read and tried various tips and tricks like adding the terminal to have *Full Disc Access* (I've added that to `/bin/rm`, `/bin/zsh` and `/usr/local/bin/bash` as well), and I've run `csrutil disable` multiple times from Recovery mode. I've also removed the ACL entry stating: `0: group:everyone deny delete` from the folders. I'm still not able to remove the folders: `Applications`, `System`, `Library`, `Volumes` and `Users`.

I've read, and tried the tips of these posts too, but to no avail:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437604/146412
- [Can't delete folder - operation not permitted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361044/cant-delete-folder-operation-not-permitted)

  - Not sure how to remove the rootless thingy on the one folder of mine which displays this, but even if `System` has this, I should be able to remove the others, right?

The last attempt from `terminal` looked like this:

```
my-mac-mini:~ myuser$ sudo -s /bin/zsh
root@my-mac-mini ~ # cd /Volumes/Local
root@my-mac-mini Local # ls -ledO@ Applications System Users Library Volumes
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root  admin  sunlnk     64 Feb 25 00:10 Applications
 0: user:myuser allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  sunlnk     64 Mar 12 20:51 Library
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 root  wheel  restricted 96 Mar 12 20:51 System
    com.apple.rootless   0 
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  admin  -          64 Mar 12 20:51 Users
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  hidden     64 Mar 12 21:16 Volumes
root@my-mac-mini Local # 
root@my-mac-mini Local # csrutil status                             
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
root@my-mac-mini Local # 
root@my-mac-mini Local # chflags nohidden Volumes
root@my-mac-mini Local # chflags -R norestricted System
root@my-mac-mini Local # chflags nosunlink Library
root@my-mac-mini Local # chflags nosunlink Applications
root@my-mac-mini Local # ls -ledO@ Applications System Users Library Volumes
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root  admin  - 64 Feb 25 00:10 Applications
 0: user:myuser allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  - 64 Mar 12 20:51 Library
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 root  wheel  - 96 Mar 12 20:51 System
        com.apple.rootless       0
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  admin  - 64 Mar 12 20:51 Users
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  - 64 Mar 12 21:16 Volumes
root@my-mac-mini Local # rm -rf Applications System Volumes Library Users Volumes
rm: Applications: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library/PreinstalledAssetsV2: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library/Speech: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library/AssetsV2: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library/Assets: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library/Caches: Operation not permitted
rm: System/Library: Directory not empty
rm: System: Directory not empty
rm: Volumes: Operation not permitted
rm: Library: Operation not permitted
rm: Users: Operation not permitted
rm: Volumes: Operation not permitted
root@my-mac-mini Local #
```

---

**So now I'm running out of options, and wonder if you're able to help me remove these folders (and the sub folders from `System/Library`)**

Comment: Can’t you just reformat the Local volume?

Comment: Nope, it's the one actually holding most of my "local" data, and I don't have enough space on the SSD to copy everything over to that disc.

Comment: Fix the problem of not having backups **first**.  Then mess with the storage volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like its harder than expected to actually remove these folders, so as I wanted some progress I started playing around based upon the comments on doing a backup and reformatting the volume.

After some plundering I discovered that since this volume is using APFS, I was able to create another volume on the same physical disk which I could copy all of my data to, and this volume could be renamed afterwards.

So I ended up doing the following:

- Using **disc util** I created a new volume `Local-copy` (on the same disc)
- Copied over all my data to `Local-Copy` (and some from another volume)
- Used `Free-File-Sync` to verify that the content was the same on both volumes
- Erased the entire old volume, and renamed the new to become `Local` again

So I had some luck that I hadn't used more than half of the disk space available in combination with that possibility of volumes sharing the same (physical) disc!